# How to pass stream input/output between a main process and a child process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdio

I'm trying to get two processes to "talk" to each other via `stdio`:

ping.js

```
import { readline } from '../readline';
import { sleep } from '../sleep';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

const spawnPongProcess = () => {
    const child = spawn('node',
        ['-r', 'esm', `${__dirname}/pong.js`],
        { stdio: 'pipe' });

    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
        console.error(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdout.resume();
    });

    child.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`child process error: ${err}`);
    });

    process.stdout.pipe(child.stdin);
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdin);

    return child;
};

export const ping = async () => {
    const child = spawnPongProcess();

    await sleep(1000);

    console.log('ping');

    let pong = readline();

    console.error(`Ping received: ${pong}`);

    child.kill();
};
```

I pipe the parent process' `stdout` to the child process `stdin` and the child process `stdout` to the parent process `stdin` in an effort to allow the processes to communicate via `stdio`.

pong.js

```
import { readline } from '../readline';
import { sleep } from '../sleep';

const pong = async () => {

    console.log(`Pong initiated and waiting for input.`);

    let ping = readline();

    console.log(`Pong received: ${ping}`);

    process.exit();
};

pong();
```

readline.js

```
import { question } from 'readline-sync';

export const readline = question;
```

sleep.js

```
export const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

The output is:

```
$ node -r esm src/index.js
Pong initiated and waiting for input.
ping
```

It appears that the output from the parent process (`ping`) is not getting through to the child process (`pong`). Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You piped your process' `stdout` (Writable) to child's `stdin` (Writable) and vice versa. Since data is received on the `stdin` (Readable), you have to pipe it instead of `stdout`:

```
process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Your code doesn't throw because if the stdout is a terminal, it becomes a Duplex stream.

Comment: Got it, but I still get the same problem: 
`Pong initiated and waiting for input.`
`ping`
`^C`
`➜`

I press `cntrl+c` after it hangs for input.

Comment: @Kiril Here's a simplified repro: https://gist.github.com/laggingreflex/6ba11dcae7624c00a2c2b29250c4b80c. Run `ping.js` and enter some lines

Comment: Thanks. I get the same results (as you) when I use the stream events, but my goal is to use `readline_sync`. Somehow, it's not working as I expect it. I guess I'll keep digging.